# Shiny : get an input from a module

Tags: r, module, shiny, reactive

I'm trying to get input from a module to the app server.

here is a example of what I want, the app.R :

```
library(shiny)
source("test.R")
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabPanel("tt", testUI("t"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   ret <- callModule(test, "testm")
   print(ret)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

A test module :

```
testUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel(NULL,
       textInput(ns("textInput1"), label = h5(""), value = "")
  )}

  test <- function(input, output, session, data) {
    reactive({input$textInput1})
  }
```

I would like print the content of textInput1 from the server function of app.R and to  observe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues with your code: 1) In the UI, you call the module instance `"t"`, in the server `"testm"`. These need to be identical. 2) The Module returns a reactive; this needs to be evaluated in a reactive context: `reactive`, `observe`, or `render`.

```
library(shiny)
source("test.R")
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabPanel("tt", testUI("testm"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  ret <- callModule(test, "testm")
  observe(print(ret()))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score -2):

The solution above solve the problem for the example I provided.

However, i does not solved it for my app :

I my app I have the app.R, a module1.R and a module2.R the module2 is call by the module1 which is himself call by app.R. I want to print the value of 'textInput1' from the module1 function.

app.R:

```
library(shiny)
source("module1.R")
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabPanel("Module 1", module1UI("module1"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  callModule(module1, "module1")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

module1.R:

```
source("module2.R")

module1UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel(NULL,
     tabPanel("Module 2", module2UI("module2"))
  )}

module1 <- function(input, output, session, data) {
  reactive({input$textInput1})
  ret <- callModule(module2, "module2")
  observe(print(ret()))
}
```

module2.R:

```
module2UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel(NULL,
     textInput(ns("textInput1"), label = h5(""), value = "")
  )}

module2 <- function(input, output, session, data) {
  reactive({input$textInput1})
}
```